# deploying Java with SCCM / SCUP

Tags: windows-7, java, updates, windows-update

We have a network of about 250 PC's which I want to deploy the java updates to. As distribution software we are using SCCM 2012 / SCUP 2011.

Note: I need to deploy both the x86 and the x64 version.

So I create two updates with the following rules:

`Installable Rule`

```
Registry Value 'HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion' exists
```

`Installed Rule`

```
Registry String 'HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\Java7FamilyVersion' Begins With '1.7.0_11'
```

Now the **problems**:

- `java.exe` is running on the computer (due to a open browser window for example): the update routine of java uninstalles the old java version; the install routine failes because `java.exe` is still running (although it has been uninstalled). Next time the user reboots no java is installed on the machine
- some users enable the auto update function of java. So whenever a new version is released it gets updatet automatically (that is not the problem). But in the next deployment cycle `SCCM` trys to install the previous update again. (7U12 was released and autoupdatet, but `SCCM` still has 7U11 and trys to install that although the user has a newer version)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem (Java.exe is running)

I use a powershell script for installing Java, which (among other things) closes the big 3 browsers. I'll paste it below for reference:

```
function Get-ScriptDirectory{
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    try {
        Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path -ea 0
    }
    catch {
    Write-Warning 'You need to call this function from within a saved script.'
    }
}

function Get-Architecture{
    return $(gwmi win32_operatingsystem).OSArchitecture
}


$Path = Get-ScriptDirectory

#Close all instances of IE, Firefox, & Chrome
Get-Process | where {$_.ProcessName -match "iexplore"} | Stop-Process -Force
Get-Process | where {$_.ProcessName -match "chrome"} | Stop-Process -Force
Get-Process | where {$_.ProcessName -match "firefox"} | Stop-Process -Force

#Install
Start-Process -FilePath "$Path\jre-6u41-windows-i586.exe" -ArgumentList "/s /v`"/qb REBOOT=ReallySuppress JAVAUPDATE=0 WEBSTARTICON=0 SYSTRAY=0`"" -Wait

#Also Install the 64-bit JRE if on a 64 workstation
if(Get-Architecture -match "64")
{
    Start-Process -FilePath "$Path\jre-6u41-windows-x64.exe" -ArgumentList "/s /v`"/qb REBOOT=ReallySuppress JAVAUPDATE=0 WEBSTARTICON=0 SYSTRAY=0`"" -Wait
}

#Import reg keys to disable auto updating
reg import "$Path\JavaUpdate.reg"
```

You may also notice that it installs the 32 bit java on *every* machine, and installs the 64 bit java on 64 bit machines after a 64 bit check of the OS.

I package this script up with the Java exes into an sfx that unpacks and runs

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -file C:\Temp\Java\install.ps1
```

For your second question, there are TWO reg keys that Java checks for auto updating:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy\EnableAutoUpdateCheck
HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy\EnableJavaUpdate
```

They *both* must be set to 0 to disable autoupdating (some versions of Java read one key and some read they other). I deploy the reg keys with the package as you can see in the script, but I also use SCCM 2012s DCM and set these as configuration items, and enabled remediate on them to make sure they are always 0.