# Is it possible to block Ask toolbar and McAfee from installing during Java and Acrobat updates?

Tags: java, updates, adobe-acrobat

Some of my users are required to have Java installed on their machines for specific applications.  I have been instructing them to become more aware of automatic updates from Oracle.  My problem is that, although warned, some of them are missing the Ask Toolbar checkbox when updating Java.  Is it possible to block that install whether they check the box or not?  The same for McAfee and Chrome during the Acrobat update.

Comment: Use the enterprise version and install it silently, like [this](http://superuser.com/questions/554703/deploying-java-with-sccm-scup/557259#557259)

Comment: There is a similar older question here http://superuser.com/questions/220897/can-i-permanently-prevent-java-security-updates-from-installing-yahoo-toolbar. Doesn't look like much has changed since then.

Comment: **hate oracle and their bloatware.

Comment: Much more recent question: [How can I prevent Ask.com Toolbar from being installed every time Java is updated?](http://superuser.com/questions/549028/how-can-i-prevent-ask-com-toolbar-from-being-installed-every-time-java-is-update)

Comment: also duplicate to this mcaffee http://superuser.com/questions/692999/how-can-i-prevent-mcafee-security-scan-from-being-installed-bundled-with-other/936949#936949

Answer (score 5):

Use the enterprise version and install it silently, like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/554703/deploying-java-with-sccm-scup/557259#557259). Acrobat can be installed the same way, they usually have 'enterprise' versions which don't come with the bloatware.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out and comment back after.