# Can I tell windows to never allow specific apps (or apps with specific publishers) to be installed?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus

Periodically I get a panicked call from my mum because her computer is saying it's got a virus and she needs to renew her antivirus in order to fix it. She's on a licensed copy of Windows which has built in antivirus. I go through the motions of checking for infection (or I did the first few times), but it invariably is because someone has installed some McAfee product that starts throwing up alarming pop-ups in an attempt to trick her into paying them. I uninstall the crapware and she's fine again for a few months.

The fact that she (or probably my kids) installs software that bundles McAfee trialware is obviously the root problem but my attempts to prevent that in the past have caused more issues. Yes, she'll probably get a real infection at some point and I do what I can to make sure she has adequate backups.

My question is: Can I at least set something up that will block McAfee products from being installed? She doesn't need them. They don't add any value, and they cost me a few hours of my time every few months.

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/692999/how-can-i-prevent-mcafee-security-scan-from-being-installed-bundled-with-other

Comment: Ooh, I wonder if adding them to untrusted publishers in the certificates section of internet options would work and not cause problems. Not sure where I would get their cert from - if the one on their website would match for example.

Comment: @Gantendo Yes, Software Restriction Policies looks perfect. I'll do that next time I go round there. Thanks :-)

Comment: You'd get it from the .exe file's "Properties > Digital Signatures".

Comment: @JesseBugden Sounds like a plan. I'll mark this as a duplicate so that others with the same problem get directed to the answer.

Comment: Yes @user1686 , or SRP sounds like it will allow me to use a download of their installer to do basically the same thing. So I think my question is answered, pending me actually going around and trying it out. Should I get one of you to make that an answer I can accept, make an answer myself or can I mark my own question as a duplicate of the one Gantendo linked?

Comment: @JesseBugden I flagged it. Soon some mod will come along and mark it as a duplicate I think. I hate bloatware.